# Selected Option Value Doesn't Change HTML Element On Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using [Curry](http://Curry%20-%20Currency%20Conversion%20DDM) jQuery plugin for Currency Conversion. I have stored selected currency in a cookie using jscookie. Everything is working perfectly but when the page is reloaded, the HTML element doesn't change with the selected option value. It only changes when I click it manually.

↠ ↠  **HERE'S A [DEMO](https://indiawav.com/downloads/indian-pop-2/)**

**Here is a modified version of curry.js**

```
/*!
 * Curry currency conversion jQuery Plugin v0.8.1
 * https://bitbucket.org/netyou/curry-currency-ddm
 *
 * Copyright 2015, NetYou
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/GPL-2.0
 */

(function ($) {
var qc;
    $.fn.curry = function (options) {

        // Setup a global cache for other curry plugins
        if (!window.jQCurryPluginCache)
            window.jQCurryPluginCache = [{}, false];

        var output = '',
                rates = {},
                t = this,
                requestedCurrency = window.jQCurryPluginCache[1],
                $document = $(document),
                dropDownMenu,
                item, keyName,
                i, l, rate;

        // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
        var settings = $.extend({
            target: '.price',
            change: true,
            base: 'USD',
            symbols: {}
        }, options);

        this.each(function () {

                var $this = $(this),
                    id = $this.attr('id'),
                    classes = $this.attr('class'),
                    attrs = '',
                    tempHolder;

            // Add class or id if replaced element had either of them
            attrs += id ? ' id="' + id + '"' : '';

            if (classes) {

                attrs += ' class="curry-ddm"';

                if (classes)
                    attrs += ' ' + classes + '"';
                else
                    attrs += '"';

            } else {

                attrs += '';

            }

            // keep any classes attached to the original element
            output = '<select' + attrs + '></select>';

            // Replace element with generated select
            tempHolder = $(output).insertAfter($this);
            $this.detach();

            // Add new drop down to jquery list (jquery object)
            dropDownMenu = !dropDownMenu ? tempHolder : dropDownMenu.add(tempHolder);

        });

        // Create the html for the drop down menu
        var generateDDM = function (rates) {

            output = '';

            // Change all target elements to drop downs
            dropDownMenu.each(function () {

                for (i in rates) {

                    rate = rates[i];
                    if (i == savedCurrency) {
                        output += '<option value="' + i + '" data-rate="' + rate + '" selected="selected">' + i + '</option>';
                    } else {
                        output += '<option value="' + i + '" data-rate="' + rate + '">' + i + '</option>';
                    }
                }

                $(output).appendTo(this);

            });

        };

        if (!settings.customCurrency) {

            // Only get currency hash once
            if (!requestedCurrency) {

                // Request currencies from yahoo finance
                var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: {
                        q: 'select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair="USDINR,USDEUR,USDCAD,USDGBP,USDILS"',
                        format: 'json',
                        env: 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'
                    }
                });

                // Set flag so we know we made a request
                window.jQCurryPluginCache[1] = true;

                jqxhr
                        .done(function (data) {

                            var items = data.query.results.rate;

                            // Add the base currency to the rates
                            rates[settings.base] = 1;

                            for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {

                                item = items[i];
                                keyName = item.Name.substr(item.Name.length - 3);

                                rates[keyName] = +item.Rate;

                            }

                            generateDDM(rates);

                            window.jQCurryPluginCache[0] = rates;
                            $document.trigger('jQCurryPlugin.gotRates');

                        })
                        .fail(function (err) {

                            console.log(err);

                        });

            } else {

                $document.on('jQCurryPlugin.gotRates', function () {

                    generateDDM(window.jQCurryPluginCache[0]);

                });

            }

        } else {

            generateDDM(settings.customCurrency);

        }

        // only change target when change is set by user
        if (settings.change) {

            // Add default currency symbols
            var symbols = $.extend({
                'USD': '&#36;',
                'GBP': '&pound;',
                'EUR': '&euro;',
                'JPY': '&yen;'
            }, settings.symbols),
                    $priceTag, symbol;

            $document.on('change', this.selector, function () {//alert();
                    var $target = $(settings.target),
                        $option = $(this).find(':selected'),
                        //$option = $(this).attr('selected'),
                        rate = $option.data('rate'),
                        has_comma = false,
                        money, result, l = $target.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {

                    $price = $($target[i]);
                    money = $price.text();

                    // Check if field has comma instead of decimal and replace with decimal
                    if (money.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
                        has_comma = true;
                        money = money.replace(',', '.');
                    }

                    // Remove anything but the numbers and decimals and convert string to Number
                    money = Number(money.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''));

                    if ($price.data('base-figure')) {

                        // If the client changed the currency there should be a base stored on the element
                        result = rate * $price.data('base-figure');

                    } else {

                        // Store the base price on the element
                        $price.data('base-figure', money);
                        result = rate * money;

                    }

                    // Parse as two decimal number with .
                    result = Number(result.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/));

                    // Replace decimal with comma after calculations
                    if (has_comma) {
                        result = result.toString().replace('.', ',');
                        has_comma = false;
                    }

                    symbol = symbols[$option.val()] || $option.val();

                    $price.html('<span class="symbol">' + symbol + '</span>' + result);

                }

            });

            //////
        }
//        $('#body').ready(function () {
//            setTimeout(function () {
//                qwe();
//            }, 1000);
//        });

       qc = function qwe() {
            var $target = $(settings.target),
                    //$option = $(this).find(':selected'),
                    //$option = $(this).attr('selected'),
                    $option = $('#curry-ddm option[selected="selected"]'),
                    rate = $option.data('rate'),
                    has_comma = false,
                    money, result, l = $target.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {

                $price = $($target[i]);
                money = $price.text();

                // Check if field has comma instead of decimal and replace with decimal
                if (money.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
                    has_comma = true;
                    money = money.replace(',', '.');
                }

                // Remove anything but the numbers and decimals and convert string to Number
                money = Number(money.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''));

                if ($price.data('base-figure')) {

                    // If the client changed the currency there should be a base stored on the element
                    result = rate * $price.data('base-figure');

                } else {

                    // Store the base price on the element
                    $price.data('base-figure', money);
                    result = rate * money;

                }

                // Parse as two decimal number with .
                result = Number(result.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/));

                // Replace decimal with comma after calculations
                if (has_comma) {
                    result = result.toString().replace('.', ',');
                    has_comma = false;
                }

                symbol = symbols[$option.val()] || $option.val();

                $price.html('<span class="symbol">' + symbol + '</span>' + result);

            }

        }

        // Returns jQuery object for chaining
        return dropDownMenu;

    };

//    function asd(){
//        alert('lkk')
//    }
})(jQuery);


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

**Custom-prices.js //this shows the custom option values**

```
var savedRate, savedCurrency;

var selectElement = '#curry-ddm'; //selected id or class of curry

var targetf = '.edd_price, .edd_price_option_price, .edd-cart-item-price, .cart-total, td.edd_cart_item_price, span.edd_cart_amount';

var options = {
    target: targetf,
    change: true,
    base:   savedCurrency,
    symbols: {
      'USD' : '$ ',
      'GBP' : '£ ',
      'INR' : '₹ ',
      'ILS' : '₪ ',
      'CAD' : 'C$ ',
      'EUR' : '€ ',
    }};


jQuery(function(){
jQuery( selectElement ).curry( options ).change(function(){
        var selected = jQuery(this).find(':selected'), // get selected currency
        rate = selected.data('rate'), // get currency rate
        currency = selected.val(); // get currency name
        Cookies.remove('site_currency', { path: '/' });
        Cookies.remove('site_rate', { path: '/' });
        Cookies.set('site_currency', currency, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        Cookies.set('site_rate', rate, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        console.log( currency, rate );
     });
    });

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     var CookieSet = Cookies.get('site_currency');

     if (typeof CookieSet === "undefined") {
       savedRate = 1;
       savedCurrency = 'USD';
       console.log('CookieSet Empty. Set to '+savedCurrency);
     }
     else {
      savedRate = Cookies.get('site_rate');
      savedCurrency = Cookies.get('site_currency');
      console.log('CookieSet read from cookie. Saved Rate: '+savedRate+' Saved currency: '+savedCurrency);
     }

     jQuery( selectElement ).val( savedCurrency );

});
```

Comment: you have not assigned a value to `savedCurrency`.

Comment: What is `Cookies`? Is that a cookie library you're using, as it's not a standard keyword. I'd also *strongly* recommend you don't modify the source of a third party library. If the owner of `curry.js` releases an update with an important bug fix, you won't be able to use it without manually amending the code again. Always extend the library, or use a different one which meets all of your needs.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Cookies is a variable from [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) which I am using to store the currency data in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

- Your problem:  Your cookies aren't saved on the initial load.
- The solution:

In your

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

where you set your variables if the cookie is undefined

```
if (typeof CookieSet === "undefined") {
```

you need to add:

```
    Cookies.set('site_currency', savedCurrency, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    Cookies.set('site_rate', savedRate, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you.  When I go to that demo and reload the page, I still see all currencies listed.  Also, I viewed the page's source and it looked nothing like your sample code in your question.